# How can I use System.Commandline.DragonFruit to parse options if the options are not preceded with double dash

Tags: c#, console-application, command-line-arguments, system.commandline.dragonfruit

I have an existing console app that takes option args that don't have the -- in front of them. For example:

```
./myapp businessDate=20230128 type=charley location=nashville
```

Currently I parse the `args[]` array tokens and split them around the `"="` to get the key/value

I can't change that, because other programs already call it that way.  But it appears that DragonFruit needs to have it this way instead.

```
./myapp --businessDate=20230128 type=charley --location=nashville
```

So my question is, **can DragonFruit be configured to *NOT* use the `--` prefix on options** when I use the equals sign to separate the key from the value the way I currently do it in the example above?  I believe the answer is *"no"*, because of the Posix compliance.  But maybe I missed something.

#### What I Tried

I ran the example program here [Building your first app with System.CommandLine.DragonFruit](https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api/blob/main/docs/Your-first-app-with-System-CommandLine-DragonFruit.md)  And it worked fine when I ran it:

```
$ dotnet run --int-option=123 --bool-option=true
The value for --int-option is: 123
The value for --bool-option is: True
The value for --file-option is: null
```

But when I tried it without the `--`, this way instead, it gave me errors, and I was hoping it would work as above:

```
$ dotnet run int-option=123 bool-option=true
Unrecognized command or argument 'int-option=123'.
Unrecognized command or argument 'bool-option=true'.
```